# derivative with respect to function in numerical work

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, chain-rule

In some numerical work I'm doing, I have a specific expression for a certain quantity $h$ that I'm looking for, but which relies on several integrals over an unknown function $g(x)$. In other words, something like this:
$$ h(x,g(x))= A(x)\int_{x-a}^x B(x^{\prime})g(x^{\prime})dx^{\prime}\left(\int_{x-a}^x C(x^{\prime})g(x^{\prime})dx^{\prime}\right)^{1/2} $$
where the primes on $x$ designates the dummy argument, differentiation otherwise.
Fortunately, I have a nonlinear equation relating $g(x)$ that I can solve (say, $f(g(x))=0$), looking the same way with multiple integrals over $g(x)$. The problem is, I don't know how to solve it yet, depending on what operations I'm allowed to do on the expression. $x$ itself is not really an independent variable, more of a function depending in a highly non-linear way on input parameters (it's a position). It acts more as a label. In fact, we don't really see $h(x,g(x))$ or $g(x)$ as functions of $x$, but rather $h(g)$ as a function of $g$ (and other variables) and $g$ as an independent variable, a physical quantity. They just 'happen' to depend on $x$, the position.

The question I have may seem like a stupid one, but I'm a bit mixed-up right now. Say I want to solve $f(g(x))$ with a Newton-Raphson method, which means I need $f^{\prime}(g)=\frac{df(g(x))}{dg(x)}$: since $g(x)$ is considered as a variable, can I do the $g(x)$ derivative without having recourse to the chain rule? To me it would seem like cheating. But in a much simpler analogue case I constructed the function $f(g(x))=0$ for solving with Newton-Raphson and did the trick for $f^{\prime}(g)$:
$$ \frac{d}{dg(x)}\int_{x-a}^{x}A(x^{\prime})g(x^{\prime})dx^{\prime} = \int_{x-a}^{x}A(x^{\prime})\frac{dg(x^{\prime})}{dg(x)}dx^{\prime} = \int_{x-a}^{x}A(x^{\prime})dx^{\prime} $$
the integral representing any member of $f(g)$. Considering that for this case $f(g)$ can be written as $f(g(x))=p(g(x))+g(x)=0$, I also rewrote $f(g(x))$ as
$$ g(x)=-p(g(x)) $$
and solved as regular relaxation problem. In both cases I got the exact same answer.

In another case, there's a complete working (ie. converging) code that needs the quantity:
$$ \frac{dh(x,g(x))}{dg(x)} $$
where
$$ h(x,g(x))=a(x)g(x) $$
for simplicity. In that case, the former was given by
$$ \frac{dh(x,g(x))}{dg(x)}=a(x) $$

Since it seems to be working in last two examples, why can we do this? (if we really can do it) Is there a rigorous answer for this, or it's some kind of trick in numerical problems? Or is this one of these gray areas a physicist would go in?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you know and what you want to do. There is more than one way to interpret a question like "Can I do the $g(x)$ derivative without having recourse to the chain rule". Do you want to compute $g'(x)$ or do you want to compute the derivative of some function with respect to the variable $y=g(x)$. Why is the application of the chain rule even an issue? I have no idea how to interpret $f(g) \rightarrow g = f(g)$.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't so clear. By $f(g)\rightarrow g=f(g)$, I mean that I have a Newton-Raphson type function $f(g)=0$, but that I don't need to actually solve for g with NR since $f(g)=h(g)-g=0$, say, and I can just rearrange the equation as $g=h(g)$.

Comment: Thing is, I have an non-linear equation for $g(x)$ which I don't know exactly how to solve yet. I'm thinking NR, or maybe something else, it depends if I can do the operation I'm talking about. The NR function $f(g)=0$ I constructed has several integrals over $g$, so in order to do $f^{\prime}$, I need to do the $g$ derivative of these integrals, like you said, as $y=g(x)$. What I wonder, is if I can put the derivative inside the integral and do as in the example above. The problem with the chain rule is that it would complicate way too much my problem.

Comment: I've seen an actual working code which needed at some point the quantity $\frac{d h(g(x))}{d g(x)}$ where $h(g(x))=a(x)g(x)$, say, and the former was simply written as $a(x)$. $x$ is itself a highly non-linear "function" derived from an iteration process; I don't know if it has anything to do with it and the whole procedures converges.

Comment: I encourage you to update your question with as much specific information as possible. Explain carefully any deviations from standard notation. It does not matter if your text is long if it is precise. I think this will increase your chance of getting useful answers.

Comment: Updated. It's funny how sometimes we think we are clear after a couple of readings but in fact we aren't. Hopefully it's now more understandable. Thanks a lot for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have not understood your problem completely, so this is only a partial answer.

I believe you are interested in a function $g : I \rightarrow J$, but you do not have an explicit formula for $g$. Here $I$ and $J$ are real intervals. However, it is known that $y = g(x)$ satisfies an equation of the form $$f(x,y) = 0,$$
where $f : I \times J \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. In this situation, you can certainly try to apply Newton's method. It takes the following form
$$ y_{n+1} = y_n - \frac{f(x,y_n)}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y_n)},$$
where the initial value $y_0$ should be close to the target value $y=g(x)$ to ensure convergence. I want to stress, that the derivative is merely the regular partial derivative of $f$ with respect to its second variable and that the chain rule is not involved here.

It is entirely possible that computing this derivative will be quite expensive in your specific case. It may be worthwhile to apply the secant method instead. It converges at a slower rate than Newton's method, but can be substantially faster because it only requires $1$ rather than $2$ function evaluations per iteration. Ideally, you should combine the secant method with bisection in order to obtain a method which is robust.

You mentioned a specific example, that of 
$$h(x,g(x)) = a(x)g(x).$$
I much prefer to write
$$h(x,y) = a(x)y.$$
With this notation all confusion evaporates and we have
$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}(x,y) = a(x).$$
The notation you cited is common in physics texts. I object to it precisely because of the confusion it can generate.

EDIT: It seems prudent to mention the related case of 
$$k(x) = h(x,g(x)).$$
Then if $h = h(x,y)$ and $g = g(x)$ are differentiable, we have that $k=k(x)$  is differentiable, with
\begin{align}
k'(x) &= \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(x,g(x))\cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial x}(x) + \frac{\partial h}{\partial y}(x,g(x))\cdot \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} (x) \\
& = \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(x,g(x)) + \frac{\partial h}{\partial y}(x,g(x))g'(x).
\end{align}

Comment: Ah I think I understand! It's about total versus partial derivatives? With total derivatives the chain rule is essential whereas with partial derivatives the variable $y=g(x)$ is considered an independent variable of its own? And in fact, that would mean that my second equation is correct, which means in my case that computing the derivative with finite differences in unnecessary, simply doing the last integral would do.

Comment: And just be sure, the correct way to do Newton-Raphson with an array **y** is like this: $$y_{n+1}|_{x_i}=y_{n}|_{x_i}-\frac{ f(x,y_n)|_{x_i}}{\frac{\partial f(x,y_n)}{y}|_{x_i}}$$ apply all corrections at the same time and iterate?

Comment: I believe that the difference between total and partial derivatives lies at the heart of the matter and that your interpretation is correct. I have added what I think is a relevant example to my answer. As for the second part of your first comment, I am not entirely sure, because I don't follow you.

Comment: Except for an (obviously) missing $\partial$ your Newton iteration is correct.Normally, I would be fanatical about it and write $$y_{n+1}(x_i) = y_n(x_i)  - \frac{f(x_i,y_n)}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_i,y_n)}.$$

Comment: Ah great, now everything is much clearer to me! Thanks a lot for your help, it's very appreciated. I'll also keep in mind the bit you added to your answer.